# Not getting any data back

Tags: reactjs

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
```

import {useForm} from "react-hook-form"

const SubmittionBox = () => {

```
const{reg, handleSubmit} = useForm()

const onSubmit = (data) =>{
    console.log(data)
}


return (
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} ref={reg}>
    
       <input type="text" placeholder="Type Name Here"  name ="name" required ref={reg}/>
       <input type="Submit"/>
   
</form>
)
```

}

export default SubmittionBox

When I hit the submit button, the only thing I get back is Object and not the data that I put in the text box

Comment: Looking at the front page of the docs for this, it looks like you have to use the register function that useForm returns. https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/handlesubmit

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function App() {
  const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm();

  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    console.log(data);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <input
          type="text"
          {...register("name")}
          placeholder="Type Name Here"
          required
        />
        <input type="Submit" />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

One of the key concepts in React Hook Form is to register your uncontrolled component into the hook. This will make its value available for both the form validation and submission.